# Installing SQL Server version 10.50.4000 is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2008 R2 version `10.50.4000` on a virtual machine running Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I try to install SQL Server, I get an error that, when I look it up, says I need to install and configure .NET Framework 3.5 first.

When I try to install via add features, it fails without telling my why, and I have to restart the server.

When I try to install manually, it says I have to use the installer.

When I try to install via PowerShell (Import-Module ServerManager and Add-WindowsFeature as-net-framework), I get the following error:

> Add-WindowsFeature : Installation of [.NET Framework 3.5.1 Features]
>   .NET Framework 3.5.1 failed. The server needs to b e restarted to undo
>   the changes. At line:1 char:19
>   + Add-WindowsFeature <<<<  as-net-framework
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Add-WindowsFeature], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FeatureMessageDetail,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFeatureCommand

There has been more failed attempts, but I can't remember all that I have done that has failed, I have had people breathing down my neck all day, so I skipped the recording what I have tried step in the name of speed... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered trying on a different / new VM?

Comment: You might give a try to [System File Checker](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) and [System Update Readiness Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14668). If neither helps, provision a new VM for fresh start. And *keep the logbook* even if in a hurry. When boss asks what's taking so long, you can use the logbook to show that you haven't been just goofing off all day long.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, unfortunately they didn't work. For now I guess I will have to use the QA system like my boss wants. I hope I got the point that using the QA system for R&D is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. This is how I got it working... I used a CD.

I don't know why it worked. I didn't even have to use a key, and it was the same version I downloaded multiple times from the Microsoft website...

Comment: If someone can propose a better answer, I will try to test and change the answer to that.